# xdotool could not move mouse inside firefox

Tags: firefox, mouse, scripts, xdotool

I have been trying for many days to get xdotool to move and click inside firefox but I couldn't. So please help me.
My script was simple but it didn't work :

```
#!/bin/bash

firefox www.google.com # opening firefox
sleep 2 # wait 2 sec
xdotool mousemove --sync 1335 165 #moving the mouse to a coordinate
sleep 2 # wait 2 sec
xdotool click 1 # finally clicking in a button


I would appreciate it if someone can help me.
```

Comment: Can't repeat, `xdotool` will move inside Firefox.

Comment: what do you mean? I'm not understanding

Comment: I don't seem to have the same problem, the script will run and click on a button for me perfectly. It was just a comment to other people who will assist you that it isn't a general Firefox problem.

Comment: have you been able to move it inside firefox? could you please give me a short example?

Comment: Well I just ran your script and it worked... I had to adjust the position to move to because of screen sizes, but other than that it was fine.

Comment: maybe I am running it wrong. Also I am using Centos not Ubuntu. I am running my scripts ./test.sh in the terminal.

Comment: No, that is the right way to run it. Does Firefox open for you?

Comment: of course firefox will open for me. Earlier, I opened the terminal then I sudo chmod 777 tst.sh and after that I ran it as : ./test.sh ( anything wrong?

Comment: Well you shouldn't do `chmod 777 test.sh`, you should do `chmod +x test.sh`. I mean when you run the script, does Firefox open or not?

Comment: @Tim - `chmod 777` makes rwx for all users, so it should also work (manual [here](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html)). **user301153**  Please edit your question question and make it clearer what the specfic problem is *(and did you mean ``chmod 777 test.sh`)*?

Comment: @Wilf I know it works, but I wouldn't recommend it... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I found the solution and it works for both Ubuntu and Centos :

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/firefox &
sleep 2
xdotool mousemove 1335 165
sleep 2
xdotool click 1
```

Comment: Except the original script works - try it out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

original script only works if firefox self backgrounded.  You obviously have different environments.

Note  you can do both xdotool actions all in one command, as xdotool itself can sleep

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/firefox &
xdotool sleep 2 mousemove 1335 165 sleep 2 click 1
```

WARNING:  how well can you rely on firefox appearing exactly where xdotool thinks it is?

You may like to add some xdotool (or other) a commands to
 1. wait for firefox to actually appear and load the expected page
 2. position and resize the firefox window where you expect it to be

If you don't you may be asking for troubles further down the road.

Note: you may like to look at visgrep from the xautomation package.  This can look for specific sub-images in a screen dump, so as figure out exactly where the mouse should be clicking (and that it is actually present) regardless of where firefox opened its window.

Basically you are only just beginning your journey into remote control of applications.